# How can a VM work out the address of the host node?

Tags: ip, virtual-machine, ip-address, host

How can a Linux VM work out the IPaddress of the host node?

I need to connect to the IP address of the host node. I also need to know when it changes as it could be a dynamic IP. I need it to connect to a service there.
Is there some way to check this, irregardless of the type of VM, VMWare, Xen, Virtual Box?

It needs to be a Linux script, and should work regardless of the host operating system, whether Linux or Windows

Comment: Unless you tell us what sort of VM system you are using, there's little chance of an answer.

Comment: @bmargulies It should in principle be able to work on any VM. It is supposed to be a Linux script that should be able to connect outside the VM and deduce the IP. eg, I can retrieve the hosts IP address by reading a web server's response of the IP which made the connection, but I'd prefer something with no dependencies outside the host itself.

Comment: No such luck. How could you tell the difference between the effect of the VM host from some NAT box? It can't be done.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to bridge a network adapter in the VM with one on the host, making it a dymanic IP address. As such it will always be on the subnet as the host adapter.

Next thing is to run an HTTP service on the host IP, that the VM will scan its network range on. The IP the service responds on will be the IP of the host. Having an IP service on the host is not ideal, but it is the best I can come up with.